# about static text link

Tags: web

what is meant by 'static text link'with reference to a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static text link would be the type `<A HREF="www.mysite.com/link">` with a relative or absolute URL which search engines can easily follow and spider.

This is as opposed to a link created in a javascript function which cannot be indexed by search engines.

```
<A HREF="javascript:myfunction()">Click Here</A>
```